# laravel passing database array from controller to view

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

hello people here is my code below for `controller`

```
$siteinformation = DB::table('siteinformation')->where('Site',$myarr[0]['site'])->select()->get();

print_R($siteinformation); will display

Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [Site] => site1 [Nickname] => friend [ProgramID] => 1 [CreateDateTime] => 2014-06-03 18:05:39 ) )
```

I am trying to pass it to view

```
return Redirect::to('sbs_site')->with('siteinformation',$siteinformation);
```

In my view i have...

```
@if(Session::has('siteinformation'))
@foreach ($siteinformation as $key => $value) 

{{ $value->Nickname }}

@endforeach
    @endif
```

Iam gettng an error `Undefined variable: siteinformation`

my route file contains... `Route::post('sbs_site', array('uses' => 'myController@sys_config'));`

what could be the problem??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you don't need to redirect; probably you are doing it wrong, instead you should pass the data to the view directly using something like this:

```
$siteinformation = DB::table('siteinformation')
                     ->where('Site',$myarr[0]['site'])
                     ->get();
// View Name: "sbs_site.blade.php"
return View::make('sbs_site')->with('siteinformation', $siteinformation);
```

Then in the view:

```
@foreach ($siteinformation as $value) 

    {{ $value->Site }}
    {{ $value->Nickname }}

@endforeach
```

But if your really need to use a redirect then you may do it like this:

```
// Route Is: "sbs_site"
return Redirect::to('sbs_site')->with('siteinformation', $siteinformation);
```

Then in your view:

```
@if(Session::has('siteinformation'))

    @foreach (Session::get('siteinformation') as $value) 

    {{ $value->Site }}
    {{ $value->Nickname}}

    @endforeach

@endif
```

Comment: even i want to do without redirecting, but its not working , i get an error `Undefined variable: siteinformation`

Comment: It should work if you load the view directly from the controller, what `URI` you are using to see the page and what is your view name?

Comment: your second answer is exactly same as mine,ya that worked...` view:make` did not work.. `uri =http://localhost/sup/public/sbs_site` `sbs_site` is my view name... i get an error message on the uri page...

Comment: It must work if you did everything properly, check it again. There is nothing very complex, it's a very simple task in `Laravel`.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me...

in view

```
     @if(Session::has('siteinformation'))

     @foreach (Session::get('siteinformation')as $key => $value) 

     {{ $value->Nickname}}

      @endforeach

     @endif
```

In controller

```
    return Redirect::to('sbs_site')->with('siteinformation',$siteinformation);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your view file is not getting session set if(Session::has('siteinformation')), because you did not set session in your controller. You set in your controller 'siteinformation' as a normal variable. If you want to set session, instead of this.

```
Redirect::to('sbs_site')->with('siteinformation',$urserializedobj);
```

Do this

```
Session::put('siteinformation',$urserializedobj);
Redirect::to('sbs_site');
```

OR

Simply don't check session in your view instead of this

```
if(Session::has('siteinformation'))
```

Just do this

```
if (!empty($siteinformation)) :
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't know why u are redirecting to pass it to the view

```
return View::make('yourview',array('siteinformation'=>$siteinformation));
```

This will do the trick if you can make the view directly from the controller
BUT
if u need to redirect than i suppose you can serialize your array or change it to json first because the with function passes the data as flash so only strings

```
$urserializedobj = $siteinformation.toJson();//if this doesn't work try serealizing
return Redirect::to('sbs_site')->with('siteinformation',$urserializedobj );
```

now in your view you can do this

```
@if(Session::has('siteinformation'))
 $siteInformation = json_decode(Session::get('siteinformation'));
 @foreach ($siteinformation as $key => $value) 

 {{ $value->Nickname }}

 @endforeach
@endif
```

Comment: i tried to your first solution but did not work it will make a view but does hold any variable values.. :( let me try your second solution...

Comment: second solution,I am getting an error `Call to a member function toJson() on a non-object`